# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, 20.04, uefi

I'm intending to update my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution to the 20.04 LTS version. After googling a solution I've found that there are many ways to go about solving this issue. From the following options which one is the preferred one?

1. Delete Ubuntu 18.04 disk partition and redo the Ubuntu live USB installation guide, such as given by [itsFoss](http://https:/itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/);
2. Use the update manager in Ubuntu, although I don't know how to specify the correct version I'm looking for to update.
3. Backup and Install live USB Ubuntu on top of the current Disk Partition that holds my current version of Ubuntu.

If there is any better way than the ones I've listed, which one.

Important note!: I don't need any data that is stored on the Ubuntu Partition.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just an opinion but I would probably reinstall (1) if there was nothing I wanted to keep on the old install. (2) is just as valid though, you can set update manager to only offer LTS versions for version upgrades. Set that and only 20.04 will be offered currently.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an opinion on the 3rd option? [Quora Similar Question](https://www.quora.com/I-have-a-dual-boot-setup-Windows-and-Ubuntu-I-want-to-upgrade-the-Ubuntu-I-have-tried-the-command-line-update-manager-everything-nothing-works-However-I-have-a-bootable-Ubuntu-USB-How-can-I-update-the-Ubuntu-without) The 2nd answer do this quora similar question to mine made me favour that option, as it seemed to be quite straight forward

Comment: "Preferred" seems a matter of opinion. The "best" solution is the one are comfortable with and understand how to troubleshoot if you encounter problems. You have an erroneous assumption in #2: Update Manager can ONLY migrate you to the next LTS (or non-LTS) release. You can't choose because there is always only one or zero choices. If you don't have a preference, and since there is no data that must be preserved, try ANY of them. They will all get you there.

Comment: I don’t know if there is a material difference between 1 and 3 but by deleting the partition yourself you know no old files will remain that could have unexpected consequences.